# Does convexity on a set implies hessian PSD on the boundary?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a **closed convex** set with nonempty interior.
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be **twice differentiable** on $C$. We also assume that it is **convex** on $C$:

$$ (\forall x,y \in C) (\forall \alpha \in [0,1]) \quad f((1- \alpha)x + \alpha y) \leq (1- \alpha)f(x) + \alpha f(y).$$

My main question is : can we say that the Hessian of $f$ is positive semidefinite on $C$?

*Some comments:*

The basic result I know holds when $C$ is an *open* set ; so applying such result on the interior of $C$, we immediately get that for all $x \in {\rm{int}}~C$, $\nabla^2 f(x) \succeq 0$. So my question is about what happens at the boundary.

What is also clear is that if I assume further that $f$ is of class $C^2$ on $C$ (and not only twice differentiable), we could pass to the limit from the interior to the boundary of $C$ to conclude that yes, $\nabla^2 f(x) \succeq 0$ for all $x \in C$.

I have been trying to find a counterexample, but every example of "twice differentiable but not $C^2$" function I find is highly nonconvex, so I start to wonder if convexity and twice differentiable implies $C^2$? After all, it is known that:

- convex functions are always continuous in the interior of their domain
- the subdifferential of a convex function has a closed graph ; so differentiable convex functions have a continuous gradient

So my secondary question is : is the hessian of a twice differentiable convex function always continous?

Comment: What does it mean to be twice differentiable on a closed set? Is $C$ strictly contained in the effective domain of $f$ (i.e., $C\subset \{x:f(x)<+\infty\}$?

Comment: It means that $f$ is twice differentiable at $x$, for every $x \in C$. This implies that $C$ is included in some open set $U$ where $f$ is twice differentiable. In particular, $C$ is in the interior of the effective domain. I believe that for this question we can assume the fuction to have a full domain.

Comment: Assuming that $C$ is contained in an open set $U$, on which $f$ is twice differentiable in addition to being twice differentiable on $C$, we can be sure that the Hessian of $f$ is psd on all of $C$. To see this, just apply the result you've referenced to the open set $U$, which contains $C$.

Comment: The standard result requires the function to be twice differentiable and convex on an open set. Unfortunately your suggestion wouldn't apply, because $f$ is only assumed to be convex on $C$, not $U$.

Comment: Yes this was a misunderstanding, thanks for clarifying.